# ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using OpenWrt

Tags: aws-sdk, openwrt, iot, arduino-yun, aws-iot

I'm trying to install [AWS-IoT-Arduino-Yún-SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-arduino-yun/#installation-on-mac-oslinux) following the instructions and got this erros:

`pip install paho-mqtt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2281, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1991, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler`

Any ideia of what could be done here?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue [upgrading the OpenWrt-Yun image on the Yún](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSysupgrade).

Basically I saved a .bin file to a SD card and plugged into my arduino yun board. 
Then, following the instructions in the link above did the work.